# Comparision Operator Issue

Tags: java, math

Hi I am facing an issue in java which I am unable to debug.

I have set a double variable  as

```
double minMean = (Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

I have another double variable

```
double mean = -5000;
```

when I try the following condition

```
  if( mean>minMean)
             print mean
```

the line "print mean" doesn't get executed. Any pointers why this is not working,

Comment: I want to check the condition, I am doing some operation in if block, my question is: why this condition is false

Comment: `print mean` id a dead code, it will never go to that statement, because mean < minMean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Double.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) is the minimum positive value. The minimim finite negative value is simply `Double.MAX_VALUE` with `-` sign in front:

```
double minMean = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
```

[IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) floating point numbers have the MSB bit reserved as sign bit. So, you have same amount of positive numbers as negative numbers. You just need to flip the sign bit to get the negative value.

Comment: I had checked the code at my end 'double minMean = -Double.MAX_VALUE;' is also not working for same code.

Comment: `-Double.MAX_VALUE` is the least finite value. The actual least value is –infinity.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of `Double.MIN_VALUE`:

```
A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2-1074
```

Since your number is negative it will not be larger.

Comment: You can try `- Double.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 4):

You are mistaken as to the meaning of MIN_VALUE:

> MIN_VALUE
>
> A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2-1074.

smallest positive, i.e. `MIN_VALUE > 0`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and found out

```
System.out.println("Min value is "+Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

Min value is 4.9E-324

Your print command is not executed because your no. is larger.